# Php, error with readfile, downloaded files do not open

Tags: php, readfile

I am using the following code to download files that are stored outside of the public folder.

```
  $mime_type = mime_content_type("{$_GET['file']}");
  define("IMG_LOC","/var/www/domain.com/upload/");
  $filename = $_GET['file'];
  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header('Content-Type: '.$mime_type);
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename(IMG_LOC.$filename));
  header('Expires: 0');
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
  header('Pragma: public');
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
  readfile($filename);
  exit;
```

The problem is, file downloaded using this script is not usable. Excel is opening empty, powerpoint tells "there is an error reading" and word tells its missing a converter. Whereas, if I download the same files using ftp and open them manually, the files open properly, showing that the files are not corrupt.

For info, this is getting called from another page as : `file.php?file='. $filename`

Any help will be welcome. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing the path to your file:

```
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize(IMG_LOC . $filename));
  readfile(IMG_LOC . $filename);
```

You should also add validation for the filename to avoid security problems.

If you still have a problem, you should also check the exact output of the script, perhaps there are php warnings or messages before your file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm deducing that `$filename` is not the absolute path to the file you're seeking and hence why you define the `IMG_LOC` constant with a path. It's clear from there that `filesize($filename)`and `readfile($filename)` will not likely give you what you want.

Try concatenating the constant before the `$filename` variable like so...

```
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize(IMG_LOC . $filename));
readfile(IMG_LOC . $filename);
```

Also, consider that this code is susceptible to header-injection attacks as well as other security issues such as the user supplying you with a filename on your server that you may not want them to see. For example if I call your script with the query string `?file=yourscript.php` I will be able to download your actual PHP code and potentially see any sensitive information you might not want exposed like your database password, or worse.

Also, `mime_content_type` is a **deprecated** function and should be replaced with the [Fileinfo](http://php.net/Fileinfo) extension instead.

Comment: Thanks Sherif. Any idea how can I prevent this ?file=yourscript.php issue ? You have a point here.

Comment: @Jeremy: I quickly dissected your script, at the end you find some code which checks against that the file must be inside the upload folder: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27626888/367456 - maybe the other comments are of some use for you, too.

Comment: @Jeremy The best approach is typically to rely on a whitelist of files (i.e. `in_array($file, $listOfSafeFilesToUse)`) where possible. Where the origin files are not statically allocated (i.e. are user uploaded or usually expanding/modified) you probably want to rely on storing the files in some database table where you can later query for them and use that as your whitelist instead of hard-coding it into your script. You should probably also rely on some unique identifier that does not expose the real filename to the user (like an auto increment id from your database or similar).

Comment: @Jeremy by _storing the files in some database table_ I mean storing the filenames, rather than actual file contents. The actual files can remain on disk.

Comment: Hi @Sherif, thanks. Yes filenames are already getting stored in the database. And user uploaded files are all renamed. So these two things I am taking care of already :)

However, I was interested to know how can I stop people from downloading files using address as `file.php?file=contact.php` ?

Comment: I see what you mean. That sounds like a great solution. Thanks @Sherif

Answer (score 1):

You script has various issues which all in all will prevent it from *properly* working. I roughly go through the lines and leave some comments, write a little summary then and offer another code-example with the comments incorporated:

```
$mime_type = mime_content_type("{$_GET['file']}");
```

You don't need to wrap the `$_GET` superglobal in curly brackets and then into double quotes. It's just not necessary for that parameter. You seem to be distracted at this point.

Anyway, this mime-type thing isn't necessary as the mime-type is not interesting if you want to offer the download. You take `application/octet-stream` instead and you can take care later on for a more specific mime-type:

```
$mime_type = "application/octet-stream";
```

Then at the wrong position you define the `IMG_LOC` constant:

```
define("IMG_LOC", "/var/www/domain.com/upload/");
```

This belongs at the very top of the script instead as you define the configuration by that.

In the line:

```
$filename = $_GET['file'];
```

you don't do any further error checking this opens up your script to directory traversal and path injection attacks which actually turns the script as you have it into a *backdoor*. Any file the script has access to on that server can be downloaded.

The next two lines are more or less correct then:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: '.$mime_type);
```

For the next header:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename(IMG_LOC.$filename));
```

I would extract the basename earlier and just pass a variable here. Same for the content-length header later:

```
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
```

Then you have this block of caching headers, as you serve the file from disk I don't think those are actually necessary, so I would remove them:

```
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
```

The readfile line seems ok, you could do some error checking however:

```
readfile($filename);
```

And the last line I don't understand, as the script is at the end anyway, why exit?

```
exit;
```

My suggestions after this little review:

Gather the information which files should be served and how they must be named.  Gathering such information will allow you to close the directory traversal issue which you have to close first.

Second putting the logic part above the output (and the configuration above the logic) should allow you to order the script in a more useful manner allowing you to handle issues with the mime-type for example easier when you maintain the script (or the caching if it is really an issue).

```
<?php
/**
 * download a file
 *
 * parameter:
 *
 *  file - name of the relative to upload folder
 */

const IMG_LOC = "/var/www/domain.com/upload";

// validate filename input
if (!isset($_GET['file'])) {
    return;
}
$filename = $_GET['file'];
$path     = realpath(IMG_LOC . '/' . $filename);
if (0 !== strpos($path, IMG_LOC)) {
    return;
}
if (!is_readable($filename)) {
    return;
}

// obtain data
$basename  = basename($filename);
$mime_type = "application/octet-stream"; # can be improved later
$size      = filesize($path);

// output
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: ' . $mime_type);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $basename);
header('Content-Length: ' . $size);
readfile($filename);
```